# what is an Irish greeting to be said to someone in the evening?

Tags: expressions

Is there an alternative phrase for greeting someone in the evening a la Top of the morning to you?

Comment: [*“**Top of the evening to you, Hadley**,” he said when the butler opened the door.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Top+of+the+evening+to+you+hadley%22) And [here are 903 more written instances](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Top+of+the+evening+to+you%22+-%22hadley%22), to people *not* called Hadley.

Comment: [Tom Carey](http://www.macmillandictionaryblog.com/top-of-the-morning-to-yourself), at the Macmillan Dictionary Blog, warns that even ' Top of the morning to you' has become archaic: ' "Top of the morning to you”, or more casually “Top o’ the mornin’ to ya”, is a well-known traditional Irish greeting that Irish people don’t really use any more – at least not without irony, in my experience.'

Comment: @FumbleFingers Nonsense, everyone in Ireland is called Hadley and they only ever address others by that name regardless of what their actual name is. I never thought I'd see you stoop so low as to post such xenophobic lies about a proud warrior race like that.

Comment: "Tráthnóna maith daoibh" (per Google),  But not really a question for a English language site :-)

Comment: @John: Xenophobic? *Moi?*

Comment: Not sure 'archaic' gets across the point that anyone saying  “Top o’ the mornin’ to ya” in real life would sound at least incongruous or more likely really stupid.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard any evening-specific greetings, but there are some general ones given [here](http://www.fluentin3months.com/irish-english/):

These mean "Hi, how are you?"

```
How are ye keepin’? How are ye? How’s the form?
```

You'll also hear "Are you all right?" (still meaning "how are you?") or in informal situations "What's the craic/Any craic?" (pronounced crack, and having nothing to do with drugs).

Comment: These answers are  spot on and very common - though be aware they are all slang so work okay in a casual or friendly environment. In a formal or work environment stick to "Good Evening!"